# Same Name Class with Different Build Types

Tags: android, android-build-type

I have class utility.java on my android program, where the class function is connect to a link API. All is done. But now I want to use Build Types Debug and Relase for different link API. I know to use Build Types for every assets, but can i do same thing for every java class?
I need your help. Thanks.

Comment: i mean you are not able to put onBackPressed in MainActivity also right?

Comment: I don't understand the question, whats the problem? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: so is it give you error?

Comment: check out my answer i hope it will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just need CLEAN BUILD AND REBUILD this android. 
Hey stackoverflow, can you just remove my question. HEHE.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.notificationdemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.demo_layout);


    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }

}
```

Try to put like this

Comment: yes I have, but onBackPressed not working. my app still close and android destroy app. not like if  I press home button.

Comment: so you want to exit it first from fragment and then from Activity?